# Passport local auth plus passport mongoose local are not accepting email as username

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I am using passport local strategy and passport mongoose local to create a user and check user authentication. However, I wanted to explore the option using email instead of username. I followed what the document says and I am getting unauthorized. Can someone tell me why I am getting an error, and it works if I just use the username as login.

From passport-local-mongoose 
Note: usernameField: specifies the field name that holds the username. Defaults to 'username'. This option can be used if you want to use a different field to hold the username for example "email".

And from passport local strategy
By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, options are available to change the defaults.

I have tried to set both true at the same time and I also have tried to set one true and another one off. I will get the same error

express 4.16.0
express-session 1.15.6
mongoose 5.1.2
passport 0.40
passport local 1.0.0
passport local mongoose 5.0.0

passport.js

```
module.exports = function (passport, LocalStrategy, User) {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true,
        session: true
      },
      function(req, username, password, done) {
        return done(null, req.user);
      }
    ));
    passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
    passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
};
```

model/User.js

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, default: ''},
    username: { type: String, unique: true, uniqueCaseInsensitive: true, required: true, default: ''},
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, uniqueCaseInsensitive: true, default: ''},
    profileImage:{ type: String, default: ''},
    timestamp: {type: String, default: () => moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a") }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'email'});
UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserSchema', UserSchema);
```

signinForm.js

```
<form class="form-signin" action="/users/signup" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign up</h1>
    <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">Name</label>
    <input type="bane" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name='name' required autofocus />

    <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
    <input type="bane" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name='username' required autofocus />

    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name='email' required autofocus />

    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name='password' required autofocus/>  

    <label for="inputConfirmPassword" class="sr-only">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputConfirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name='confirmPassword' required autofocus/>  

    <input type='file' class='form-control' id='inputFile' name='profileImage' />
    <div style="height: 10px"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
</form>
```

routes/users.js

```
router.post('/signup', upload.single('profileImage'), function(req, res, next) {

  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;

  if (req.file) {
    console.log('Uploading File...');
    var profileImage = req.file.filename;
  } else {
    console.log('No File Uploaded... Setting to no image');
    var profileImage = 'noimage.jpg';
  }

  UserController.createUser(req.body, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        err: err
      });
      return;
    }
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function() {
      //res.render('index', {currentUser: user, title: 'Product Page' });
      res.redirect('/');
      return;
     });
    return;
  })
});
```

I ended up getting authorized and 401

Thanks in advance.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the 'return' at the end of UserController.createUser(), you need to wait for the result of passport.authenticate()

Comment: I see, you try to access "/users/signup" with your app, but the Node.js route is '/signup'. If your router is not handling the  '/users' prefix, this is an error.

Comment: Hey Copro, I have a users route so /users/signup works. My req.body has all the informations I needed except passport isn't taking in email as username